# nodeschool Streams adventure [HTTP SERVER]

Tags: node.js

I found a bit of intriguing behavior on an exercise about nodejs.

The aim is to transform POST data of a request to uppercase and send back using stream.

My problem is I'm not having the same behavior between these two pieces of code (the transform function just take the `buf` and `queue`it to uppercase) :

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var tr = through(transform);
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        req.pipe(tr).pipe(res);
    }
});
```

---

```
var tr = through(transform);
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        req.pipe(tr).pipe(res);
    }
});
```

The first one is correct and gives me :

```
ACTUAL                             EXPECTED
------                             --------
"ON"                               "ON"
"THEM"                             "THEM"
"BUT,"                             "BUT,"
...
```

My version with the  `tr`var outside :

```
ACTUAL                             EXPECTED
------                             --------
"QUICK."                           "QUICK."
"TARK'S"                           "TARK'S"
"QUICK."                       !== "BIMBOOWOOD"
"TARK'S"                       !== "BIMBOOWOOD"
"BIMBOOWOOD"                   !== "SO"
"BIMBOOWOOD"                   !== "SO"
...
```

For info the transform `function` :

```
function transform(data) {
    this.queue(data.toString().toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: Oh, actually, the second piece of code has `tr` outside the callback so this is clearly a timing issue.  `tr` is being changed quickly while the code inside the callback is being run less frequently because it is waiting for createServer to finish every time.

Comment: @JakeSellers since transform is just a function I don't understand why there would be some kind of timing issue. Unless unlike Java, the `data` value is changed in call1 before it finishes by call2

Comment: If that second piece of code gets called two or more times very quickly, `tr` is going to be reset a greater number of times than the callback for create server is called, which would explain why it looks like your values are offset or staggered by two.

Comment: node is asynchronous by nature, so unlike java, many functions like createServer are going to start, but not be waited on, so anything outside of that callback is going to happen independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var http = require('http')
var through = require('through')

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.error("Been called")
    if (req.method != 'POST') return res.end('send me a POST\n');

    var tr = through(function(buf){
        this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase())
    })
    req.pipe(tr).pipe(res)
})
server.listen(parseInt(process.argv[2]));
```

Run this example. Note the console.error call. The createServer requestListener is being called twice, so two instances of 'tr' are being created. If 'tr' is created outside the callback there is only one. This results in unexpected behavior when the requests and writes don't happen in the order we get oddness.

I suspect this is not intended behavior for the through module.

Answer (score 0):

The comments in the problem are correct that it's an asynchronous issue (the biggest pitfall for somebody new to Node in my own experience).

PSB's solution is correct, but I wanted to be able to break the through instance out into a separate function rather than have to define it inside the createServer callback function.

The through instance needs to be wrapped in a closure so this.queue keeps the intended context.

```
var http = require('http');
var through = require('through');

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
        if(req.method==='POST'){
                req.pipe(tr()).

                pipe(res);         
        }
});
server.listen(process.argv[2]);

var tr = function(){
        return(through(
                function(buf){
                        this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
                })
        );
};
```