# Nodeschool's Stream-Adventure #7 HTTP Server

Tags: node.js, streaming

I'm doing something wrong in Nodeschool's stream-adventure exercice #7 - Http server. Here's an exercice description [gist](https://gist.github.com/nelson777/7e80ff12ee96fa7967c2).

This is the code I've done so far:

```
var http = require('http');
var through = require('through2');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method != 'POST') 
        return;

    var stream = through(function write(buffer, encoding, next) {
           this.push(buffer.toString().toUpperCase());
           next();
       });

    req.pipe(stream).pipe(res);
});
server.listen(process.argv[2]);
```

I got a "not ok 3 successful exit code" error on verify. So I though some things:

- Maybe I need res.end() -> didn't work, and failed the other tests
- Maybe I need this.queue instead of this.push(), next(), as the execice showed. Didn't work: object didn't have the queue method.
- Maybe I need a status code in the res, so I put this: `res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });`. Same message: "not ok 3 successful exit code"
- I tried the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938293/nodeschool-streams-adventure-http-server). With similar results (queue method not available).
- I even tried it with learnyounode http uppercaserer exercice and the resul was the same.

Now, I've seen [here](https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/84) that a couple of years ago there was a problem with this exercice. Is it really correct ?
If it is, can somebody gave me a hint on what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Once I was going through nodeschool lessons too.. When I have hit a dead-end, I resorted to looking into the test case and then did my best to identify when it went wrong.. Their defautl message "test failed" is not very useful...

Comment: Well I tried that. AFAIU, since I'm still a Node newbie, it expects a `process.exit(0)`. But it's a server. If I exit it'll obviously close the server. So no other calls would be possible. Anyway I try to put it after the pipe line. And then finnaly the 3rd test passed, but the 2nd don't. Because I've closed the server. So what do I do ? expect only two calls to the server ? I don't think this is very appropriate.

Comment: I tried to expect only 2 calls with `count++; if (count >= 2) process.exit(0);` and with `var count = 0;` on beggining. It failed with same error.

Comment: Can you please give a link to the source code of the lesson itself?

Comment: I've put it in the beggining of the question. It's in github's gist here: https://gist.github.com/nelson777/7e80ff12ee96fa7967c2

Comment: It is a readme for the lesson, not a source code.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean. Souce code for what ? that was the only descrition of the problem. You can install this lessons with `npm install -g stream-adventure` after installing node. Here is the page where I knew about them: http://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers

Comment: Thanks for the name, we are closer now. The source code for a problem will be one of the folders in here: https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure/tree/master/problems Please find the exact one, and we'll have more clues on what is going on.

Comment: This one: https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure/tree/master/problems/http_server. But please  I don't wanna see the solution. I just need a tip. If I wanted to cheat I would have done that before.

Comment: No, I am suggesting to look into the test unit(s), and debug your application. It is a real-life experience programmers face - to verify the output of the application. If you alter `https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure/blob/master/problems/http_server/index.js` to add some `console.log` messages on expected and received output then you will see where it fails, and start looking into right direction.   If you do not want to do that yourself, then you are actually asking "**Debug this code for me, because I do not want to see why it fails**"

Comment: What I'm seeing is that in that file, line 30, it expects a exit with 0 as result (success). And in line 48 it kill the spawned process. I've used in the past Python's pexpect module and I'm thinking this should work more or less the same. My question is: if it kills the process how can I get the event and return the correct exit code ? I've tried `server.on('close',function() { process.exit(0); });` but it didn't work.

Comment: Node shall return 0 by default already. You still decided not to try reproducing the problematic test case, well that's fine.  Only uncertainty in the code I see is: `if (req.method != 'POST') 
        return;`. That might actually leave the connection hanging, try changing it to: `if (req.method != 'POST') 
        return res.end();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72758/discussion-between-nelson-teixeira-and-alandarev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today after sleep and with a fresh head I try to grasp the test case again. So I see that in

```
ps.once('exit', function (code) { 
    t.equal(Number(code), 0, 'successful exit code'); 
});
```

it expects a successfull return (0). I've put `console.log(code)` inside and it came out 143 (SIGTERMed process). That's because of line 48 (ps.kill), that kills 
the process. So I changed the test code from expecting 0 to 143. And it succedded. But I still didn't look at the solution even seeing it succedd. I wanted to
make the original test code work. So I google a bit and found this:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
    process.exit();
});
```

when I put this in the code it finally worked. Now I've finally checked the solition and the reference solution DIDN'T work. As I expected from problem's description.
Anyway I've made it and learn a lot more than I was expected to learn with this lesson. Hope this helps someone.

**Edit:**

When I tried to open an issue report for this ([link](https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure/issues)), I realize that there was already a report on this subject ([link](https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure/issues/119)). The real problem was that I was trying to use stream-adventure with an older version of Node (0.10.33) and this problem doesn't happen in the newer 0.12.0 (latest as I write this).

Comment: That is why I asked you to look into source code of a test... (not solution). My congratulations on succeeding, and indeed it is way more empowering to sort out those unexpected issues, rather than complete everythign smoothly on a first attempt. I highly suggest to go one step beyond and create an issue report on their project page with this description.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks.